# How to add option "Any" in a dropdownlist when data is filled from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, drop-down-menu

I have dropdownlist where values are added by connecting to database.

Here's my code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="devicetype" DataValueField="devicetype"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PHSNew %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [devicetype] FROM [dx_devices]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now I want to add one more option "Any" in the dropdownlist.

How can I add?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
ddl_MyItems.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Any--", String.Empty));
ddl_MyItems.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `DropDownList` you need to add `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` in order to allow that, your `DropDownList` would be like:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
DataTextField="devicetype" DataValueField="devicetype">

<asp:ListItem Text="Any" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: this will add items at the beginning of the dropdownlist which is something most coders with similar problem would not want.

Answer (score 2):

instead of adding a data source on the .aspx page, get the results of your sql query in a dataset in your codebehind and manually add all the items from the dataset to the dropdownlist and add 'Any' item at the end of your dropdownlist.

EDIT

Alternative method:

Add the attribute `OnDataBound="DropDownList1_DataBound"` to your existing dropdownlist.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="devicetype" DataValueField="devicetype" OnDataBound="DropDownList1_DataBound"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Add the following code to your codebehind. This will add the `Any` item at the end of the dropdownlist after binding the datasource you have have specified on your .aspx page.

VB

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim ite As New ListItem
        ite.Text = "any"
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(ite)
End Sub
```

C#

```
protected void DropDownList1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListItem ite = new ListItem();
    ite.Text = "any";
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(ite);
}
```

Comment: i did dis way
"AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
and 
<asp:ListItem Text="Any" Value="Any" />

thank u :)